# SUM after COUNT and Group By MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to ask about SQL in mysql. Im stack over 1 hour :( 
I have sql :

```
    SELECT TZL.IsMissed, COUNT(TZL.ChatID) as Amount FROM tblLog TZL group by TZL.IsMissed
```

And the result :

```
| IsMissed | Amount |
|        0 |    100 |
|        1 |    500 |
```

I want add one more column after Amount column, let say the name of new column is **SumAmount**.
 i want **SumAmount** value is **SUM** of the Amount Column.

| IsMissed | Amount | SumAmount | 
| 0 | 100 | 600 | 
| 1 | 500 | 600 |

I already try sql like below :

```
SELECT
    tbl.*,SUM(tbl.Amount) as SumAmount
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            TZL.IsMissed,
            COUNT(TZL.ChatID) AS Amount
        FROM
            tblLog TZL
        GROUP BY
            TZL.IsMissed
    ) tbl
GROUP BY
tbl.IsMissed 
WITH ROLLUP
```

But with **ROLLUP** the result is add a new one row, not column. Anyone can teach me for this ? 
Thanks for answer

Comment: What's the point of adding a redundant column to the result set?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath : after i got the SumAmount i want to find the percentage value, and then i will add one more colum alias with value ((SumAmount/Amount)*100)

Comment: Sum of Amount when grouped by IsMissed in both queries is always same as Amount in inner query, what is the point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to approach this.  I would calculate the value in the `from` clause:

```
SELECT TZL.IsMissed, COUNT(TZL.ChatID) as Amount, tt.SumAmount
FROM tblLog TZL CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as SumAmount FROM tblLog) tt
GROUP BY TZL.IsMissed, tt.SumAmount;
```

Comment: thanks, its work. The key is use CROSS JOIN. ok, i must learn about cross join.